# Proper set up for SDL in Qt Creator

Tags: c, windows, qt, sdl, qmake

I have a problem which I can't solve. I downloaded the latest version of SDL and I extracted to my C: drive. I opened a new project in Qt and edited the pro file. I saw a tutorial and I added following lines:

```
LIBS += -LC:/SDL/lib -lSDL
INCLUDEPATH += C:/SDL/include/SDL
```

The compilers recognize that SDL is there but when I try to compile it I get following error:
*cannot find -lSDL*.
Anyone knows where the problem is and how to solve it? I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Try removing the space between the -L and the path

Comment: @Maz: yeah, sounds like a typo for which we have a close reason. This is why things like cmake or pkg-config is better, although pkg-config is not that trivial on Windows. Just in case: `CONFIG += link_pkgconfig` and `PKGCONFIG += sdl` that way.

Comment: Removing the spaces didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have C:/SDL/lib/SDL.dll available?

Comment: @lpapp yes I have, it is called SDL2.dll

Comment: @Valinho: so why do you use `-lSDL` instead of `-lSDL2` then?

Comment: @lpapp didn't really know what this argument was exactly for. I changed it but it still doesn't work. :/

Comment: @Valinho: have you re-run qmake after the change?

Comment: @lpapp Yep, still doesn't work, but thanks anyways.

Comment: @Valinho: The problem will be elsewhere. Please provide an SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`LIBS += -LC:/SDL/lib -lSDL2
INCLUDEPATH += C:/SDL/include/SDL`

You seems use SDL2 library